# User doing downvotes intentionally to my question?

Tags: support, down-votes

I downvoted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18371653/why-does-switch-in-java-rely-on-break) and left [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18371653/why-does-switch-in-java-rely-on-break?noredirect=1#comment26980940_18371653). Afterwards, [this user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2532299/varun) downvoted many of my questions without any reason.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Downvotes are supposed to be intentional. They are also anonymous, and no one is required to give a reason. How do you know it is Varun?

Comment: At that moment, we had discussion on this question. He is not pleased with my comment. You can check his comment...

Comment: This is called serial downvoting, it sucks, it is unjust, and usually you can't do anything against it. If you are lucky, the system detects it and they will be reversed tomorrow.

Comment: Four question with different tags asked by me. They are all downvotes suddenly. It is just serial voting..

Comment: Yep, probably. So read the duplicate I've just pointed out. No worries. Most likely it will be reversed.

Comment: You may or may not be right about who down voted. Be careful about such assumptions. It could be someone who came along and saw your comment exchange and didn't like what you were saying.

Comment: He first abuse.. check the comment screenshot which is deleted. Then i leave the page and 4 of the question was downvoted..